# Tkinter Scrollbar doesn't support built-in options

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

If i try to change the Scrollbar options, i have error. This is example for

`scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(console_frame, orient='vertical', highlightcolor='green')`:

`_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-highlightcolor"`

But, if we look at the `__init__` in ScrollBar class, we can see, that it should have this option, like others:

```
class Scrollbar(Widget):
    """Scrollbar widget which displays a slider at a certain position."""

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Construct a scrollbar widget with the parent MASTER.

        Valid resource names: activebackground, activerelief,
        background, bd, bg, borderwidth, command, cursor,
        elementborderwidth, highlightbackground,
        highlightcolor, highlightthickness, jump, orient,
        relief, repeatdelay, repeatinterval, takefocus,
        troughcolor, width."""
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'scrollbar', cnf, kw)
```

So, when i try to use `orient` option, method works. But it doesn't work with other options.

Comment: You have a typo - it should be highligh**t**color (you're missing a `t`)

Comment: @JRiggles yeah, sorry, but, even with highlightcolor it doesn't work. I found the issue. `tkk.Scrollbar` doesn't work with that. `tk.Scrollbar` works (i mean, it doesn't cause crash). But, it doesn't change anything at all. If i don't use `style`, i can't change the default scrollbar. I can do it if i only use another style theme in `style`, like `alt`... Is it possible to edit the default theme? (i mean, actually default, bc there is also the theme called `default`).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you should be able to style a `ttk.Scrollbar` widget by instantiating `ttk.Style()`, e.g. `style = ttk.Style()` and then configuring it as desired with `style.configure('TScrollbar', <style options here>)`

Comment: Does [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/changing-the-appearance-of-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter-using-ttk-styles) help at all?

Comment: @JRiggles thank you for the tutorial. It helps, but there is no info about other style options. And it seems like there are a few styles which can be configured... Btw thank u!

Answer (score 0):

See [the reference of the Ttk scrollbar](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_scrollbar.html). It does not support the `-highlightcolor` option.

Also to see the effect of the `-highlightcolor` option of the basic scrollbar(not Ttk scrollbar), you should set the `-highlightthickness` option to a nonzero value and give the scrollbar widget the input focus. See [the reference](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/options.html#M-highlightthickness).